# No properties shown in Data Flow Server for custom stream application

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am running Spring Data Flow Server 2.11.0-SNAPSHOT (the same problem occurs for 2.9.1, too) within a docker compose environment. I have an issue with custom stream app properties, which are not loaded anddisoplayed in the server.

I have created several stream applications with basically the following file structure:
all the same custom properties like this:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAP77.png)

I compiled everything, put it into a maven repository and registered the app in the dataflow server using `sink.filearchive=maven://org.fzj.ibg.tsm.microservices.sinks:filearchive-sink:jar:0.0.19-SNAPSHOT`

When I display the app's information, I play get the following results: [Screenshot of app properties in Data Flow Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1wMm.png). Obviously, the properties are not loaded.

Doing the same for a processor with exactly the same properties class file (except the @ConfigurationProperties tag), I get exactly what I would expect after Regierung the app: [screenshot of app properties loaded correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KIaS.png)

Any ideas, what thereon of the problem is and how it can be solved?

The Properties file look like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("sink.filearchive")
@Validated
public class FileArchiveSinkProperties {

    private File destination = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    private Boolean deleteSource = true;
    private String nameSeparator = "_";
...
}
```

I registered the properties in the application's configuration file and autowired the properties

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FileArchiveSinkProperties.class)
public class FileArchiveSinkConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private FileArchiveSinkProperties properties;
...
}
```

In addition, I created a `dataflow-configuration-metadata.properties` file in the main/resources/META-INF directory with the content:

```
configuration-properties.classes=org.fzj.ibg.tsm.microservices.applications.sinks.filearchive.FileArchiveSinkProperties
configuration-properties.names=sink.filearchive.destination, sink.filearchive.deleteSource,sink.filearchive.nameSeparator
```

I added the configuration-properties.names line later. Without it it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the spring-cloud-dataflow-apps-generator-plugin with configuration in your pom? You also need to register the metadata jar that is produced.